# Select first record each group

Tags: c#, mysql, linq, entity-framework, group-by

I'm using Entity Framework in order to connect to MySQL.

I have an incremental data which implements subversion technique. Each set of subversion record has the same `LinkedId` and separated by `UpdatedTime`.

My expectation is getting the latest version of each record from database. Thus, I write a linq statement like below:

```
public List<Entry> LoadFinalEntries(int rptId) {
    return (from ent in ctx.Entries
           where ent.ReportId == rptId
           orderby ent.LinkedId, ent.UpdatedTime descending
           group ent by ent.LinkedId into svnEnt
           select svnEnt.FirstOrDefault()).ToList();
}
```

But at the run-time, it throws an `EntityCommandCompilationException` telling that "**Specified method is not supported.**". I know that method is `FirstOrDefault`, but cannot find anyway to fix it.

Please help me to find out another way to do.

Comment: Are you use MSSQL? I was unable to reproduce this issue with that ...

Comment: Oh, sorry! I'm using MySQL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a better solution after referring [this article](http://www.xaprb.com/blog/2006/12/07/how-to-select-the-firstleastmax-row-per-group-in-sql/)

```
public List<Entry> GetFinalEntries(int rptId) {
    // Get the latest updated time for each linked id
    var latestUpdatedTimes = from ent in ctx.Entries
                             where ent.ReportId == rptId
                             group ent by ent.LinkedId into svnEnt
                             select new { LinkedId = svnEnt.Key, UpdatedTime = svnEnt.Max(ent => ent.UpdatedTime) };

    // Compare (by joining) to get full entries
    var latestEntries = from ent in ctx.Entries
                        where ent.ReportId == rptId
                        join time in latestUpdatedTimes
                            on new { ent.LinkedId, ent.UpdatedTime } equals time
                        select ent;

    return latestEntries.ToList();
}
```

Now it works fine.

Answer (score 1):

What do you think using inner query?

```
    return (from ent in ctx.Entries
            where ent.ReportId == rptId &&
            ent.UpdatedTime ==
                (from inner in ctx.Entries
                where inner.LinkedId == ent.LinkedId &&
                inner.ReportId == rptId
                select inner.UpdatedTime).Max()
            select ent).ToList();
```

Comment: Thank you! It works. Yet, I'd like to use advantages of LINQ, your query is what I did by query directly to Database.